# Why does Ctrl + Shift + C no longer open a new external terminal in VS Code?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Here is proof my VS Code is configured to accept <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + C</kbd> to open a new external terminal: [image]

Here is proof that nothing overwrites the hotkey in VS Code: [image]

The hotkey still fails if I rebind it to <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + X</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Q</kbd> still opens an Ubuntu terminal at root. I suspect VS Code registers the hotkey but Ubuntu doesn't let it open a terminal. Example: <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + L</kbd> still selects a whole line. <kbd>Ctrl + ~</kbd> still opens.

Yet I also changed nothing about this deliberately: it worked 2 weeks ago. I could reinstall my entire OS and everything from scratch, but I don't want to do that.

My is `terminal.external.linuxExec` setting is set to `x-terminal-emulator`. The issue also reproduces if I change it to `gnome-terminal`. <kbd>ctrl+shift+c</kbd> works when bound to a different command like `cursorDown`. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

I use this hotkey every day, so the fact that it doesn't work now is costly for my productivity. To not fix it means that every time I want a new terminal in my current project, I have to: open a new terminal at root and then type `/code/subfolder/projectName`.

Comment: Version: 1.78.2
Commit: b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435
Date: 2023-05-10T14:47:05.613Z
Electron: 22.5.2
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.19.0-41-generic snap
Sandboxed: No

And, I believe I installed it via that Ubuntu GUI, but `sudo apt install` might have been it also. I don't recall

Comment: 1) Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. 2) that means you installed it as a Snap. It even says so in the `Help: About` output (look carefully!)

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug. See [Open New External Terminal Not Work (Ubuntu Linux)
#179958](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179958). Since the command itself is not working, by extension, no keyboard shortcut that you bind to it will work. The issue ticket is still in a triage state, but given that both you and I can reproduce this, I'm pretty confident in its bug-ness. I'll update this post once the fix is made. You can give the issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it.

The bug seems to be specific to Ubuntu / Linux. It doesn't reproduce for me on my Windows 11 machine, and it doesn't reproduce for one of the VS Code maintainers on their macOS machine.

And most (all?) people who shared version info there had VS Code installed as a Snap. Apparently if you install it as a deb package, this is not an issue, so if you don't mind that, you can take that route as a solution.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found this by googling "`github vscode issues open new external terminal not working linux OR ubuntu`".

A good way to debug keyboard shortcut issues is how I showed you in the comments: Try the command itself that the keyboard shortcut is bound to. Then you can see if the issue is with the invocation command itself. And try binding the keyboard shortcut to a simpler command, such as `cursorDown`, which allows you to see if there is anything interfering with VS Code picking up the shortcut, such as a system-level keyboard shortcut. See also [the official keybinding troubleshooting wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues).

Comment: I left a thumbs up on the issue per your instruction. Thanks